# How to make an unauthenticated firestore REST API POST request

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The docs for Firestore's REST API are all over the shop, which I guess is excusable as it's still in beta. They seem to suggest that the REST API should follow the same rules as a gRPC client, and therefore if a path has rules saying:

`match /thing/* {
    allow create;
    allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
}`

(say I want anyone to be able to add things and then only authenticated users to see those things)

then I should be able to:

`curl 'https://content-firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/things?alt=json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"fields":{"test":{"stringValue": "foo"}}}'`

and create a document in my things collection. But I get:

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}`

Has anyone had any luck doing this? Or am I just that guy with the weird use case? Some docs mention API tokens or other google cloud auth methods.

Follow up question, if the answer is I need complex auth to do this, is there another well known strategy for presenting REST APIs on the internet that write into Firestore?

edit: I should also add, that same POST command works fine when run from Google APIs Explorer in a browser, but when I do that I'm authenticated.

Comment: On reflection I think this is probably a Bad Idea so instead I made a cloud function to do just the one thing with a lot of manual validation for security.

Seeing as Firestore doesn't have schemas anyone could really post anything in there and DDOS it or fill it up, so it seems much better to use a Function and check everything.

Answer (score -1):

Your rule says: request.auth.uid != null - so the user should be authenticated when doing a request. The behavior of the REST API is correct, since the request you do is for a user that is not authenticated you get a 403

How you authenticate that user depends on your platform. But if we assume that you are on the web, then after the user logs in, you could run the firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true).then(token => token)... method and once you have the token, add it to your url with &access=YOUR_TOKEN.

Now firebase will be able to authenticate your user with the REST API and your requests should complete as expected.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for trying. It's the POST part I'm interested in. The POST should be a create action, and should therefore be governed by the "allow create" part of the rules. You've spotted the read rule there.

Comment: Oh, ok. I over flew this part. I'm using the REST API for the realtime database and actually the behaviour there is the same. I can't access any resource (even if the resource is public) unless I authenticate with firebase id token or oauth token. I guess you could file a bug report to the firebase team. They are generally very responsive.

Comment: Ah that's really good to know, thanks! In the end I added a comment at the top level, I reckon Functions are a neater and safer solution to this problem.